# Go to a certain part of a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I made a little number guessing game, and I have made it restart afterwards if you want.
However it restarts by going back to the beginning and asking for "myname" again, how could I make it so that it instead goes back to the bit where it thinks of a number, and remembers my name from the first time?

```
import random
restart = '1'
def main():
    guessestaken = 0

    print ('Hello, what is your name?')
    myname = raw_input()


    number = random.randint(1, 50)
    print ('Okay ' + myname + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 50. You have 5 guesses.')

    while guessestaken < 5:
        print ('Take a guess.')
        guess = input()
        guess = int(guess)

        guessestaken = guessestaken + 1

        if guess < number:
            print ('Your guess is too low.')

        if guess > number:
            print ('Your guess is too high.')

        if guess == number:
            break

    if guess == number:
        guessestaken = str(guessestaken)
        print ('Good job ' + myname + ', you got the correct answer in ' + guessestaken + ' guesses')


    if guess != number:
        number = str(number)
        print ('Oh dear ' + myname + ', the number I was thinking of was ' + number + '.')

while restart == '1':
    main()
    restart = raw_input('Would you like to try again? Press 1 for Yes, and 2 for No: ')
```

At the moment it asks for my name again. I mean, it is functional, just annoying.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you split it up in multiple functions, with each asking a single question and just repeat those you want to repeat? (for example, split up the name asking into a separate function, and just call it once before the while loop)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply move

```
print ('Hello, what is your name?')
myname = raw_input()
```

before the `main()` function, so it will run only once.

You will also want to use `raw_input()` instead of  `input()` in your `main()` function.

Comment: He's probably using Python 3, in which case  `input` would be fine.

Comment: @Junuxx: No, he isn't. He's calling `raw_input()` in the last line of the script.

Comment: +1 because your answer was first.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to ask for the name outside of the `main()` function, and then pass it in for each game. You technically don't have to pass it in (python will still be able to access the variable) but it is better practice to do so.

```
def main(myname):
    # Remove the name prompt from here

...

print ('Hello, what is your name?')
myname = raw_input()

while restart == '1':
    main(myname)
    restart = raw_input('Would you like to try again? Press 1 for Yes, and 2 for No: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix would be to initialize `myname` outside of `main`, by putting `myname = ''` just under `restart = '1'`. Then, only ask the player's name if his name is unknown, i.e.:

```
if myname == '':
    print ('Hello, what is your name?')
    myname = raw_input()
```